# SVG fill patterns not displaying

Tags: qgis, svg, inkscape

I have created several custom SVG symbols in Inkscape to use in QGIS. I have several that have fill patterns, but these patterns are not displaying in QGIS. I also am having this problem with symbols in which I have inserted text. I have attached screenshots, with an example of just one of these symbols.

The symbol as it was created in Inkscape https://i.stack.imgur.com/EodGt.jpg

The symbol as it displays in QGIS https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2TYY.jpg

I am of course willing to upload files to be examined, but I am not certain of the best way to do so.

I am moderately familiar with QGIS, but I am brand new to Inkscape.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not expert enough to tell you the best way how you achieve the symbol you intend to get, but certainly it would help to convert the pattern fill to vectors. E.g. you could use inkscape to vectorize a raster image. Once you have more vertices in inkscape than just the outer border, the geometry will show up in QGIS. By the way, by editing your .svg-file in a editor and inserting after an opening Path-Tag some style-attributes with param() as shown below, you can change fill-color, outline-color, and outline-width within your QGIS-legend. But there is no choice for a fill pattern of an area within the SVG-symbol.
`<path style="fill:param(fill);stroke:param(outline);stroke-width:param(outline-width)" ...`